# Putting a string sentence from a database inside a TextField value

Tags: php, html, sql, textfield

so basically I am trying to get a sentence from a database in a value of a textfield... If I echo $f I get the whole sentence displayed so the query I did earlier should work. However, if i put it in the textfield value the value is e.g.:

*value="This" sentence="" is="" an="" example=""*

So the TextField only displays the first word of the sentence. How can I get the value to be the whole sentence instead of creating new attributes?

```
    $varName="";
    $varWert=0;
    $query='SELECT Text FROM questions WHERE 1';
    $erg=DBErg($query,$varName,$varWert);

    for($i=0;$i<count($erg);$i++){
        $f=$erg[$i]["Text"];
        echo "<input type='text' name=$i value=$f>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use htmlspecialchars. This will escape " in your value.

```
 echo "<input type='text' name=$i value="'.htmlspecialchars($f).'">";
```

Answer (score 0):

it was

```
echo "<input type='text' name=$i value='$f'>"
```

:c